# how convert lowercase to uppercase with ASCII code?

Tags: c#, string, winforms, ascii

Converting lowercase letters to uppercase, but the problem is that it deletes the uppercase letters and enlarges the lowercase letters, and I don't want the uppercase letters to be removed as well

For example

Input = AbCd

Output  = BD

```
    }
    string str;
    String s;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        str = textBox1.Text;
        foreach (int i in str)
            if (i >= 97 && i <= 122)
                s += (char) (i - 32) ;
        textBox2.Text = s ;
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong with `textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.ToUpper()`?

Comment: do you have to use ascii codes? you could just do `textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.ToUpper();`

Comment: The reason you are seeing what you are seeing is because you `if` statement excludes non lower case characters. Suggestions: use a `StringBuilder`, not a string `+=`. Consider using `char.IsLower` and `char.ToUpper`. Or just use `syring.ToUpper`

Comment: You're missing an `else` statement

Comment: You shouldn't assume that a Winform text box is ASCII, default encoding will change according to the machine that it runs on. In fact even on a machine with language set to English it is likely to be a form of UTF-8 (some machines default to UTF-16).

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the fact that there are better ways to do what you want to do, the problem is that you're missing an `else` statement, where you copy the characters that are already upper case to the new string:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = "";

    foreach (int i in textBox1.Text)
    {
        if (i >= 97 && i <= 122) s += (char) (i - 32);
        else s += (char) i;
    }

    textBox2.Text = s ;
}
```

Comment: If you really want to fix all make sure to explain `s` too...